# Python curve fitting with an infinite summation

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a curve fitting in python, which include an infinite summation.

I always got an error.

```py
from mpmath import nsum, exp, inf
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# get the data
y=[]
x=[]
for t in range(0,100,10):
    x += [t]
    y += [round(float((nsum(lambda n: exp(-(0.0002)*(n)*t),[0, inf]))),3)]
print(y)

# curve fitting
def test(t,D):
    return  [round(float((nsum(lambda n: exp(-(D)*(n)*t),[0, inf]))),3)]

                 
parameters, params_covariance=curve_fit(test, x, y)

print(parameters)
```

I hope I can get the estimated D from the curve fitting function but I always get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'),
       mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0')],
      dtype=object)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add all of the import statements to the code you posted, so that I can run the exact same code that you are running.

Comment: It would also help to include the *complete* traceback, so we can see *where* the error occurs.

Comment: Also, look carefully at the error message. The code is trying to create an `mpf` object somewhere. So (looking at the documentation for `mpmath`) it expects a  *single* `float` or `str` or an `int` or an other `mpf`. But it gets a `numpy` array of `mpf`. Hence the error.

Comment: @RolandSmith I agree, as the error is labeled "TypeError" and the data type (dtype) is shown as "dtype=object". I'm thinking that this would be easier to troubleshoot if the nsum is taken out of the lambda expression, which is very compact, and placed on a single line by itself as much as possible for isolation. Once troubleshooting is completed and the type error is resolved, the lambda can easily be reconstructed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the input and output of test() to be list

```
def test(x,D):
    return  [float((nsum(lambda n: exp(-(D)*(n)*t),[0, inf]))) for t in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you've shown, I cannot reproduce the error.

(I'm using list comprehensions to create `x` and `y`, but they are equivalent to your code.)

```
In [1]: from mpmath import nsum, exp, inf

In [2]: x = [t for t in range(0, 100, 10)]
Out[2]: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

In [3]: y = [round(float((nsum(lambda n: exp(-(0.0002)*(n)*t),[0, inf]))),3) for t in range(0, 100, 10)]
Out[3]: [150.0, 500.5, 250.5, 167.167, 125.501, 100.501, 83.834, 71.93, 63.001, 56.057]

In [4]: [type(t) for t in y]
Out[4]: [float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float]

In [5]: [type(t) for t in x]
Out[5]: [int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int]
```

As can be seen, `x` is a list of integers, and `y` is a list of floats. So there is no `mpf` in sight...

The only thing is that `test` returns a list:

```
In [6]: def test(t,D):
   ...:     return  [round(float((nsum(lambda n: exp(-(D)*(n)*t),[0, inf]))),3)]
   ...:

In [7]: test(30, 0.002)
Out[7]: [17.172]
```

The documentation for `curve_fit` is not explicit about this, but I would expect the function to just return a number like this:

```
In [8]: def test(t,D):
   ...:     return  round(float((nsum(lambda n: exp(-(D)*(n)*t),[0, inf]))),3) 
   ...:

In [9]: test(30, 0.002)
Out[9]: 17.172
```

I don't have scipi installed, but `curve_fit` should not have a problem with `x` and `y`. I don't know if it would have a problem with `test` returning a list, but that surely would not reproduce this specific error.

<strike>**Edit:**
Since there are no `mpf` objects in the data nor in the function that is submitted to `curve_fit`, it should not be possible for `curve_fit` to raise this exception.</strike>

**Edit2:**
Based on the traceback, it seems that returning a list from `test()` *is* indeed the problem. When mpmath sees the returned list *and* you are using numpy, it tries to convert the list to `mpf`. That is where it seems to goes wrong. Change `test()` to return a number instead of a list as I've shown above. That should fix it.

Comment: @Vicky See edited answer. So I think that the code that produced the error is *different* from the code shown in your question. Therefore, *please* check that this code actually produces this error. And if it does, edit your question to show the *complete error traceback*.

Comment: @Vicky See updated answer. Read the traceback carefully and reference the mpmath source code. You can see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid extra complexity by using interactive curve fitting tools. In the case of using Python I suggest checking out [SplineCloud](https://splinecloud.com/) - it has a free versatile interactive tool for curve fitting, and you can reuse curves in your code with the help of a client library for Python.

A more detailed description is available in this [article](https://splinecloud.com/features/curve-fitting/).